# Should we burninate [sunrise] and [sunset]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

I don't believe these tags add anything to the question. But I don't want to just remove them as there are some others around the fringes that I'm unsure about. [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) is often used alongside [sunrise](/questions/tagged/sunrise) and [sunset](/questions/tagged/sunset), however, as it's a natural science rather than a product or a computing concept and I think this should be burninated as well.

[azimuth](/questions/tagged/azimuth) and [ordinal](/questions/tagged/ordinal) also float around the edges but are mathematical concepts and therefore seem to have more place on Stack Overflow.

Is this logic an appropriate way of thinking about tags? Should [sunrise](/questions/tagged/sunrise), [sunset](/questions/tagged/sunset) and maybe [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) be burninated?

*If* [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) should go what about [maths](/questions/tagged/maths) and [physics](/questions/tagged/physics) or are they different somehow?

Comment: If anyone can come up with an appropriate and funnier joke about burning sunrise than I could think of I'd be grateful...

Comment: what about [tag:stars]? Care to add that to the list as well. :) It is added to several of the questions that have sunset.

Comment: Ach, I went looking for celestial objects and missed that one @Josh. I did find [tag:grammars] though, which really annoyed me...

Comment: [astronomy] may or may not be a good fit, but it sure is an interesting tag for search purposes.

Answer (score 1):

On a Q&A site about programming, [sunrise](/questions/tagged/sunrise), and [sunset](/questions/tagged/sunset) seem to add too much details that are not useful for understanding the question. I could understand [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) to mean "code about concepts usually relevant on astronomy," but not a tag for every term used in astronomy.

[stars](/questions/tagged/stars) seems used for review stars, asterisks (it seems so in [Printing *s as triangles in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047583/printing-s-as-triangles-in-java)), star field (as in [Scrolling starfield with gl_points in pyglet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470417/scrolling-starfield-with-gl-points-in-pyglet)), stars assigned to messages (as in [Will a function be added to Gmail App Script API to get the type of star assigned to a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629130/will-a-function-be-added-to-gmail-app-script-api-to-get-the-type-of-star-assigne)), the `RatingBar` class (as in [Android RatingBar doesn't accept float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338854/android-ratingbar-doesnt-accept-float-values)).

I am not sure [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) is really necessary.
If the question title is [How can I calculate sunrise azimuth for multiple locations and dates in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132513/how-can-i-calculate-sunrise-azimuth-for-multiple-locations-and-dates-in-r) or [Sunrise and sunset times based on coordinates and altitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681204/sunrise-and-sunset-times-based-on-coordinates-and-altitude), it is pretty clear what the topic is. Since normally questions are tagged with a programming language tag, I wonder if there are users who answer to [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) questions for whatever programming language used for the code.

I would rather burninate [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy), [stars](/questions/tagged/stars), [sunrise](/questions/tagged/sunrise), and [sunset](/questions/tagged/sunset).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a statement about the tags purpose and what I could find was in the ["About" page](https://stackoverflow.com/about), where it says: "*All questions are tagged with their subject areas.*". As such, I don't see why `astronomy` would need to go unless we consider a *notoriety* criteria like in wikipedia.

I'd consider `astronomy` a minor subject. Many of the questions posted there deal with certain calculations, certains API's (like [pyephem](/questions/tagged/pyephem)) that make it a useful tag for such programs.

Given that these questions are a minority I'd agree that [sunrise](/questions/tagged/sunrise) and [sunset](/questions/tagged/sunset) are too specific and should be deleted, merging the questions with [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy).

[astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy) could also include those questions related to other celestial objects. I've already retagged a few of the questions that were on [stars](/questions/tagged/stars), and one question I found tagged with [galaxy](/questions/tagged/galaxy) that was not about the tablet leaving them with [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy)